# Saving remote webpages with PHP (in PDF or screenshot)

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

I have a web application that need to cache some remote pages to be viewed in the future.

I thought that creating a pdf of the page was a good idea and I started to try some libraries, according to others question here.

I tried `Dompdf` but I had few problems just trying out the quick start example, the pdf created was not so well formatted: huge line spacing and elements not aligned.

Also, I need to save few pages at once and display a result with Codeigniter's controllers but the library just "quit" the execution and the others view can't be loaded.

How can I configure properly dompdf to work as it should?
There are other alternatives to save remote web pages?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use https://github.com/microweber/screen

**Install:**

```
composer require microweber/screen
```

**Usage:**

```
use Screen\Capture;

$url = 'https://github.com';
$screenCapture = new Capture($url);
$fileLocation = '/some/dir/test.' . $screen->getImageType()->getFormat();
$screenCapture->save($fileLocation);
```

---

[Working demo](https://github.com/microweber/screen/tree/master/demo)